# Handling dot in vue-router params using vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

If route params contains dot(.) vue redirect the route to 404. In vue 2 we can allow/handle dot in router params using following rule in webpack:

```
devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: {
          disableDotRule: true
      }
 }
```

But vue 3 use vite instead of webpack. How to handle dot in parameters now?

route example are following:

```
{
  path: your-route/:params",
  component: somecomponent,
}
```

Comment: It's usually best to go to the official source first instead of asking here. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4344

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and based on one of the question comments I went to the github issue about this problem and they recommend a plugin for vite that solves it.

Install it with

```
npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-rewrite-all
```

And add it to vite.config.js

```
import pluginRewriteAll from 'vite-plugin-rewrite-all';

export default {
  plugins: [pluginRewriteAll()]
}
```

Check out the github issue https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4344

And the plugin's github https://github.com/ivesia/vite-plugin-rewrite-all.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer not to contain only the links to the solution, but briefly describe the solution itself as well so one can easily find it at one glance or if the links should change, ...

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful! Had the same issue when I used an activation link for accounts on my webapp. The activation token was a part of the URL and included a dot.

Comment: It functions correctly in the development environment, but it fails to work with the distribution files generated by `npm run build`.

Answer (score 2):

Vite 5 allows dots in URL params without the need for any plugins. It's mentioned [here in this thread](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2415#issuecomment-1720814355).

You can update to Vite 5 with

```
npm install -D vite@latest
```